# How to call startActivityForResult from fragment's custom ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I have a fragment and inside there is a ListView.

In the ListView Item there are ImageButtons like Delete and Update

In the Adapter of ListView I have

```
EditTeam.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent intent=new Intent(getContext(),AddTeam.class);
            ((Activity)getContext()).startActivityForResult(intent, 2);

        }
    });
```

but its not returning to fragment's ActivityOnResult method

So I am guessing its the ((Activity)getContext()) part.. which needs to be something declaring the fragment?

the ActivityForResult method which is inside the fragment is the following:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode==2)
    {
       Toast.makeText(getContext(),"NEW TEAM SAVED",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

How I can fix this

Thank you

Comment: use interface for it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onActivityResult is not being called in Fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-is-not-being-called-in-fragment)

Comment: Did you override `onActivityResult()` in the Activity class, too?

Comment: the answer here I think its NOT the case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-is-not-being-called-in-fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In  you must forward results to fragment method, it's not automatic

You must receive your result in your activity's onActivityResult, the you must get your current fragment and invoke manually his onActivityResult method. Something like this:

Activity code

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // find your fragment as you need, here is by id

    // Pass the activity result to the fragment
    Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(NavigationHelper.CONTAINER_RES_ID);
    if (fragment != null) {
        fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Fragment A calls Activity B from Activity B I want to return to fragment A, so I put in both of them onActivityResult method?

Comment: You mean the Activity which includes initially the fragment?

Comment: No, when your Activity B finish it send back data to Activity A. Anctivity A catch result information in his onActivityResult method, so you need to put it only in your Activity A, because B finish, send data and doesn't receive anything.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you are passing the right **context** to the adapter. the context of the adapter must be the activity of that particular fragment in which listview is being contained.